# How to reduce space between points in a line chart?

Tags: c#, charts

How do I reduce space between points in a line chart in C#. I would like to reduce the space between the points 01 and 02 and 03, it is very big. the red line is for show the space what I want to reduce.

[image]

Comment: Please post the code that you are currently using.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-lq6ahOraOFYi1feFR3VTFtLVE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can't really tell what object library you are using from that snip. [Ask]

Comment: System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart

Comment: You may also want play with the Interval of the X-Axis but the goal is really unclear, despite the nice graphic..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want.

If you want the tick marks to appear more frequently, you will need to manipulate the [Axis.MajorTickMark](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.majortickmark(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

If you like the tick marks where they are data-wise, but want them closer together, you can manipulate the [Axis.Minimum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.minimum(v=vs.110).aspx) property and the [Axis.Maximum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.maximum(v=vs.110).aspx) property. The larger the range covered by the axis, the closer together the tick marks will become.

If you want to keep the axis range the same and the tick mark values the same, your only option is to make the chart itself smaller, which will make everything closer together.

If you want to keep the minimum, maximum, chart size, and tick mark values the same, but just want them closer together, that is physically impossible, if you think about it.